# ruby on rails with daterangepicker combining two columns into one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been using 2 different input fields, `:start_date`, `:end_date`. I'm trying to clean up the form a little and have found this [daterangepicker js](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#ex5) where I can do a start and end date in 1 input.

Instead of doing a lot of modification to the changes in my migration database, how do I keep `:start_date` and `:end_date`?

```
= f.text_field :start_date, class: 'start-form', placeholder: 'Start'
= f.text_field :end_date, class: 'end-form', placeholder: 'End'
```

my current JS

```
$ ->
  $(".start-form").datepicker
    dateFormat: "MM dd yy"
    numberOfMonths: 2
    maxDate: 0
    onSelect: (selected) ->
      $(".end-form").datepicker 'option','minDate', selected

  $(".end-form").datepicker
    dateFormat: "MM dd yy"
    numberOfMonths: 2  
    maxDate: 0
    onSelect: (selected) ->
     $(".start-form").datepicker 'option','maxDate', selected
```

With the new daterangepicker, I can make this shorter:

```
$ ->
  $('.test-new-calendar').daterangepicker
    autoUpdateInput: false
    locale: cancelLabel: 'Clear'
  $('.test-new-calendar').on 'apply.daterangepicker', (ev, picker) ->
    $(this).val picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY')
    return
  $('.test-new-calendar').on 'cancel.daterangepicker', (ev, picker) ->
    $(this).val ''
    return
```

And I have this input field:

```
= f.text_field :start_end, class: "test-new-calendar"
```

but the `:start_end` here is wrong... Would like to know what I need to combine the two columns

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is through the use of virtual attributes. In your model you can add attributes that aren't backed by the database and exist only in memory. `attr_writer` creates a standard setter method, `attr_reader` creates a standard getter method. Here we'll create our own getter and setters because we want to do something special on assignment and pass the data onto the different fields.

```
# app/models/test.rb
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :update_dates

  def start_end=(combined_date)
    dates_array = combined_date.split('-')
    start_date = dates_array[0].to_time
    end_date = dates_array[1].to_time
  end

  def start_end
    "%s - %s" % [start_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"),end_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")]
  end

  def update_dates
    dates_array = start_end.split('-')
    start_date = dates_array[0].to_time
    end_date = dates_array[1].to_time
  end

  ... rest of your code
end
```

Now that we have getters and setters, we can use them as if they were regular db-backed fields in forms:

```
= f.text_field :start_end, class: "test-new-calendar"
```

And Rails will get the value from the getter when it renders the field, and pass the value on to the setter when the form submits.

Comment: Thanks for helping me set this up. I'm getting these Invalid date, and a "-" in a blank input field. However, I'm able to select dates. http://imgur.com/iEpRr27,4A324yJ,nQTAski But it doesn't seem to be saving into my database? Did I have to do something else other than what you had set up?

Comment: The empty dates string `" - "` is a result of `start_date` and `end_date` being nil when a new record is initially presented for filling out. You'll need to decide based on the needs of your app what a blank `combined_date` should look like. As far as the data not saving, look at my edited answer to see a callback now being used to make sure that before a record is saved the proper attributes are assigned again in case they hadn't been before.